# Magento2.3 error symlink in custom email template

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates

I have a problem with one custom email, in admin panel I can previzualize it with no error but when email send I have:

> Blockquote
> Error filtering template: A symlink for "C:/Dev/wampp/www/WO_Custom/lib/web/css/source/lib/_actions-toolbar.less" can't be created and placed to "C:/Dev/wampp/www/WO_Custom/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_FR/css/source/lib/_actions-toolbar.less". Warning!symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)

When I delete

> Blockquote
> {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

I have no error but not the header.

I have no idea how can I have this email correctly. Thanks for your help

Comment: share the email template code.

Comment: {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}blablalablab{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

Comment: Does yur template in same directory where other have which already working for you?

Comment: yes I have try this solution, I don't know why just for this email I have problem

Comment: If I delete  {{css file="css/email.css"}} and {{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}, I have no error but no css